# p5.js won't working without user interaction

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

```js
let gameFound; 

function preload() {
  gameFound = loadSound('/audio/SFX_-_Game_found_03.mp3');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function gameFoundSound(){
  gameFound.play();
}

gameFoundSound();
```

Hi all here I am sharing my code I want play sound when my popup is appear there without user interaction
but in browser getting warning - The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page
and getting error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined

How I can play background music, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably too late for you, but in case anyone else comes here seeking for a solution...

This is because of a modern browser policy of not allowing audio to play without a user gesture in the context. In practice, it means that the browser won't play your audio until you have moved, clicked or tapped inside the canvas. The purpose of this is to prevent annoying audiovisual spam that we're so often treated to these days, technically any audio playback should now require input from the user to start.

**All the necessary info is found here**:
https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/userStartAudio

Basically you have to do just two little things:

1. Call `getAudioContext().suspend();` inside `setup()` **before** any other audio code is called.
2. Then call `userStartAudio();` in `mousePressed()` or any similar user gesture function.

Personally, I've done it like this (other stuff removed) so it's not called repeatedly for no reason:

```
let audioStarted = false;

function setup() {
    // Suspend audio until user gesture
    getAudioContext().suspend();

    // Initialize audio
    sound = new p5.Oscillator(); // etc...
}

function mousePressed() {
    // Start audio on user gesture
    if (!audioStarted) {
        userStartAudio();
        audioStarted = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you call the `function preload`?

Without calling it `gameFound` is undefined

Answer (score -1):

You must call gameFoundSound() in function setup(). `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined` happens when the sound (gameFound in this case) is not ready. Calling loadSound() in function preload() ensures that the sound is loaded before function setup() and draw(). An alternative would be using callback of loadSound(), when calling it outside of function preload(). More info. in the doc: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadSound.